# How to concatenation hexadecimal numbers?

Tags: python

I need to extract data from a text file where it is written by this way:

```
ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233
```

So my first question is how to convert the plaintext in order to have this format:

```
DATA= '\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x88\x99\xaa\xbb\x44\x55\x66\x77\x00\x11\x22\x33'
```

My goal after that is to concatenate the extracted data from file with the  `START_OF_DATA='\x24'.`

My second question is how concatenate `DATA+START_OF_DATA`.
In fact, at first when I test my work I just used just one plaintext, so I used this declaration:

```
clear_msg=(b'\x24\xcc\xdd\xee\xff\x88\x99\xaa\xbb\x44\x55\x66\x77\x00\x11\x22\x33')
```

I need in the end to have exactly this same format.

This is my script in python:

```
import string
import serial
import time
from array import array
import struct

with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Plaintext.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

SOF= '\x24'
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4',\
                    baudrate=230400,\
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                    timeout=0)

for a in range (0,1):
   line_array=lines[a]
   plaintxt_16b=line_array[0:32]

#The result is ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233

#clear_msg= SOF+plaintxt_16b
# print(clear_msg)
# ser.write(clear_msg)
time.sleep(0.4)

#while True:
#  print(ser.read(70))
ser.close()                # close ports
```

This is my text file `Plaintext.txt`:

```
ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `binascii.unhexlify`. Then you can simply concatenate strings until you have what you need.

```
from binascii import unhexlify
res = unhexlify("ccddeeff8899aabb4455667700112233")
print("\x24" + res)
```

Comment: I put it like this:  plaintxt_16b=line_array[0:32]
   from binascii import unhexlify
   clear_msg=binascii.unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)    IT GIVES ME AN ERROR:  clear_msg=binascii.unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)
NameError: name 'binascii' is not defined

Comment: You imported `unhexlify` and called `binascii.unhexlify`. Call it like `unhexlify(plaintxt_16b)` *or* do `import binascii` instead of `from binascii import unhexlify`.